# Something is wrong with the equation

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

There is something wrong with the equation below:

[image]

> By just **exchanging two squares at a time**, find the equality with the least amount of exchange.

For example if this question is asked for below equation, you may find the solution with **one time exchange**:

[image]

the answer will be exchanging "+" and "9" which makes the equation correct as below:

> $29+5=34$

**FYI:** Even though it is not a hint, all numbers are used only once. ($0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$)

Hint: you only swap each square once for optimal clear solution.

Comment: Do the squares we swap have to be adjacent like in the example?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis no, you can swap any square with any other square you want

Comment: A few questions – (1) can I place the brackets beside a number (like $5(6)$) to do multiplication, (2) are we doing left-to-right or order of operations?

Comment: @Hugh  left to right and you may yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@oray's edit: Here is my intented answer since no-one found it out:

> $3140\times(6+9)=2-75\times8$ (Initial layout)
>  $3140\times(6+9)-2=75\times8$ ("$=$" and "$-$")
>  $3\times40\times(6+9)-2=7518$ ("$\times$" and "$1$")
>  $3\times45\times(6+9)-2=7018$ ("$0$" and "$5$")
>  $3\times45\times(6+9)-7=2018$ ("$2$" and "$7$")

which is

> the year we are in.

I found another solution with

> 4 exchanges

which is:

> $3140\times(6+9)=2-75\times8$ (Initial layout)
>  $3+40\times(619)=2-75\times8$ (Swapped $1$ and $+$)
>  $3+40=(619)\times2-75\times8$ (Swapped $=$ and $\times$)
>  $3+40=(629)\times1-75\times8$ (Swapped $2$ and $1$)
>  $5+40=(629)\times1-73\times8$ (Swapped $5$ and $3$)
>  To arrive at $45=45$

————————————————————————————————————————————

Original post: I'm not sure if this is optimal, but I can do it in

> 4 exchanges

like this:

> $3140\times(6+9)=2-75\times8$ (Initial layout)
> $314\times0(6+9)=2-75\times8$ (Swapped 0 and $\times$)
> $314\times0(6+9)=27-5\times8$ (Swapped 7 and $-$)
> $314\times0(6+8)=27-5\times9$ (Swapped 8 and 9)
> $514\times0(6+8)=27-3\times9$ (Swapped 3 and 5)
> To arrive at $0=0$.

Comment: this is good one, but not my intended answer and 4 is actually optimal though actual answer does not require any trick.

Comment: @Oray what do you mean by "no trick"? this answer fits all the rules, does it not?

Comment: @Quintec originally i was not planning to accept 0( concept then i thought it would be okay :)

Comment: According to a comment on the OP, evaluation should be left to right, which would give $27-3\times9=216$. FWIW, I'd prefer usual operator precedence in any arithmetic puzzle.

Comment: Hopefully the new solution I found was your intended answer @Oray :)

Comment: you can only swap each square once for the optimal clear solution @lovemathboy

Comment: @lovemathboy I gave my solution here since no other good solution exists here and accepted it. I think it was kinda hard :(

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's optimal but I can do it in

> $6$ exchanges.

Solution

> Label the boxes, from left to right, by $A,B,C,\ldots,Q$. Then the exchanges are: 
>  (i) $J \leftrightarrow M$ 
>  $3140\times(6+9 -=2)75\times8$ 
>  (ii) $L \leftrightarrow M$ 
>  $3140\times(6+9 -=)275\times8$ 
>  (iii) $K \leftrightarrow M$ 
>  $3140\times(6+9 -2)=75\times8$ 
>  (iv) $I \leftrightarrow K$ 
>  $3140\times(6+2 -9)=75\times8$ 
>  (v) $A \leftrightarrow I$ 
>  $2140\times(6+3 -9)=75\times8$ 
>  (vi) $D \leftrightarrow Q$ 
>  $2148\times(6+3 -9)=75\times0$

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start it off, I can do

> 9 exchanges(thanks to @Jaap Scherphuis for reading the rules)

to end with

> $31*0(69)+4=8*7-52$

the details of which I have not quite figured out how to display in the answer.

Comment: Since non-adjacent exchanges are allowed, the above answer can actually be done in 9. It is the permutation (CJHIGFE)(LQ)(MOP) where the squares are labelled A to Q, which needs no more than 6+1+2=9 exchanges.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks, my bad, didn't read the rules carefully