# Fix the perfectly ordered equation

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

This question is follow up to [Something is wrong with the equation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71441/something-is-wrong-with-the-equation)

This time our numbers are given as below included each numbers on a keyboard order and some basic math operators next to each other once.

[image]

> By just swapping two squares at a time, find the equality with the least amount of swapping.

Note that when you put your result to Wolfram Alpha, it should say "True" as a result. so [PEMDAS](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-pemdas-definition-rule-examples.html) is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can do it in

> 5 exchanges

The swaps are:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ^ 0 + - * / ! 9 = (Swapped 9 and ^) 
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ^ 0 + - * / ! = 9 (Swapped 9 and =) 
>  6 2 3 4 5 1 7 8 ^ 0 + - * / ! = 9 (Swapped 6 and 1) 
>  6 / 3 4 5 1 7 8 ^ 0 + - * 2 ! = 9 (Swapped 2 and /) 
>  6 / 3 - 5 1 7 8 ^ 0 + 4 * 2 ! = 9 (Swapped 4 and -) 
>  To get 2 - 1 + 8 = 9

Alternate answer in the same number of swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  1 7 3 4 5 6 2 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Swapped 2 and 7) 
>  1 7 - 4 5 6 2 8 9 0 + 3 * / ! ^ = (Swapped 3 and -) 
>  1 7 - 4 5 + 2 8 9 0 6 3 * / ! ^ = (Swapped 6 and +) 
>  1 7 - 4 5 + 2 8 = 0 6 3 * / ! ^ 9 (Swapped 9 and =) 
>  1 7 - 4 5 + 2 8 = 0 / 3 * 6 ! ^ 9 (Swapped 6 and /) 
>  To get 17 - 45 + 28 = 0

Third answer using the same number of swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 2 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Swapped 2 and 9) 
>  1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 * 0 + - 2 / ! ^ = (Swapped 2 and *) 
>  1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 * 0 + - ! / 2 ^ = (Swapped 2 and !) 
>  1 9 = 4 5 6 7 8 * 0 + - ! / 2 ^ 3 (Swapped 3 and =) 
>  1 9 = 4 - 6 7 8 * 0 + 5 ! / 2 ^ 3 (Swapped 5 and -) 
>  to get 19 = 4 - 0 + 120 / 8

Fourth answer using the same number of swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  4 2 3 1 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Swapped 1 and 4) 
>  4 2 3 / 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * 1 ! ^ = (Swapped 1 and /) 
>  4 2 0 / 5 6 7 8 9 3 + - * 1 ! ^ = (Swapped 0 and 3) 
>  4 2 0 / 5 = 7 8 9 3 + - * 1 ! ^ 6 (Swapped 0 and 3) 
>  4 2 0 / 5 = 7 8 - 3 + 9 * 1 ! ^ 6 (Swapped - and 9) 
>  To get 84 = 84

Fifth answer using the same number of swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  8 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Swapped 1 and 8) 
>  8 2 3 4 5 6 7 + 9 0 1 - * / ! ^ = (Swapped 1 and +) 
>  8 2 3 4 5 6 7 + 9 0 / - * 1 ! ^ = (Swapped 1 and /) 
>  8 2 - 4 5 6 7 + 9 0 / 3 * 1 ! ^ = (Swapped 3 and -) 
>  8 2 - 4 5 = 7 + 9 0 / 3 * 1 ! ^ 6 (Swapped 6 and =) 
>  to get 37 = 37.

A quite amazing sixth answer using the same number of swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  1 6 3 4 5 2 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Swapped 6 and 2) 
>  1 6 ^ 4 5 2 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! 3 = (Swapped 3 and ^) 
>  1 6 ^ 4 / 2 7 8 9 0 + - * 5 ! 3 = (Swapped 5 and /) 
>  1 6 ^ 4 / 2 - 8 9 0 + 7 * 5 ! 3 = (Swapped 7 and -) 
>  1 6 ^ 4 / 2 - 8 = 0 + 7 * 5 ! 3 9 (Swapped 9 and =) 
>  to arrive at 32760 = 32760. (Entering "16^4/2-8=0+7*5!39" gives "True" on Wolfram Alpha)

————————————————————————————————————————————

Edit: So I realized that the question statement says that

> Note that when you put your result to Wolfram Alpha, it should say "True" as a result.

Hence we can cheese the question and use just:

> 3 exchanges

Via the following swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / ! ^ = (Original) 
>  1 2 3 ! 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / 4 ^ = (Swapped 4 and !) 
>  1 2 3 ! = 6 7 8 9 0 + - * / 4 ^ 5 (Swapped 5 and =) 
>  1 2 3 ! = 6 7 * 9 0 + - 8 / 4 ^ 5 (Swapped 8 and *) 
>  if you enter "123!=67*90+-8/4^5" on Wolfram Alpha it will return "True" as 123 != 6029.9921875 (Though it is noted that the question does mention "equality", hence this funny answer isn't valid)

Comment: :) pretty good answers

Comment: @Oray is it optimal though?

Comment: i found it 5 swaps as well, not sure 4 is possible, i will wait a day, then accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using 13 swaps:

> 1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 6 5 8 / 4 7

Which boils down to

> 14 = 14

Swaps:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - x / ! ^ =
>  1 x 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - 2 / ! ^ =
>  1 x 3 ! 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - 2 / 4 ^ =
>  1 x 3 ! + 6 7 8 9 0 5 - 2 / 4 ^ =
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 7 8 6 0 5 - 2 / 4 ^ =
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 8 6 0 5 7 2 / 4 ^ =
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 6 0 5 7 8 / 4 ^ =
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 5 7 8 / 4 6 =
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 7 8 / 4 6 5
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 6 8 / 4 7 5
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 6 5 / 4 7 8
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 6 5 8 4 7 /
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 6 5 8 / 7 4
>  1 x 3 ! + 9 - 2 ^ 0 = 6 5 8 / 4 7

I'm sure there's a solution using less swaps, so consider this the benchmark to break.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can do it in

> $9$ exchanges

Swaps

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - x / ! ^ = 
>  1 ^ 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - x / ! 2 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - x / 4 2 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 7 8 9 0 + 5 x / 4 2 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 5 8 9 0 + 7 x / 4 2 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 5 8 x 0 + 7 9 / 4 2 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 5 8 x 0 + 2 9 / 4 7 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 5 8 x 0 + 2 7 / 4 9 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 5 8 x 0 + 2 7 / 9 4 = 
>  1 ^ 3 ! - 6 5 8 x 0 + 2 7 / 9 = 4